# Scaling of group in borderpane center

Tags: javafx-2

Following Scenario:

```
BorderPane
  center
    ScrollPane
      List of other nodes
```

The ScrollPane resizes niecely to fill all the space.

Adding a Group to the picture:

```
BorderPane
  center
    Group
      ScrollPane
        List of other nodes
```

Now the group has the size of the first Element in the ScrollPane and right of it, the space is left empty.

None of the nodes has any size attribute set (prefWidth,...). Neither in the fxml, nor in the code.
Any Idea, what could be wrong?

Comment: Could you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org) ?

Comment: Andreas, I see one trouble with this schema : ScrollPane can have only 1 item of content, and not a list. What is that container?

Comment: So, it appears, that if you increase the size of the first node, the size of scrollPane increases too? (I mean, you cannot think, that it is just a collision of size of scrollPane, and of the first item)